# ngDestroy executed too late: unable to call specif dispose method

Tags: angular

I guys,
I'm having a problem using ngDestroy.  I need to call a "stop" method on a object initialized during ngInit, but when ngDestroy is called this object is already null.  If I don't call that stop method, a background process won't be stopped and after some time I start to receive errors.

How can I do it?

---

This is how I'm writing my component

```
@Component({ templateUrl: 'sample.component.html' })
export class SampleComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {

  constructor() {  }

  myObject : MyObject = null;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.myObject = new MyObject();
    this.myObject.Start();
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.myObject.Stop();   //<== when ngOnDestroy is executed myObject is "undefined"
    this.myObject = null;
  }
}
```

When ngOnDestroy is called, myObject is already undefinied so I cannot call Stop method.  If that method is not called, the background process started during ngOnInit will work forever.

How can I solve it?

Comment: Angular executes the following lifecycle hooks in sequence. Why is `ngOnDestroy` running before `ngOnInit`? https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks#lifecycle-event-sequence

Comment: @AliF50 ngOnDestroy run after ngOnInit but variable myObject is undefined, this is the problem

Comment: ngOnInit runs => initializes the object => ngOnDestroy runs, how is the object undefined at this point?

Comment: I found the problem.  ngOnInit execute an async method but in the meantime the component was destroyed because of a ngIf that became false, so ngOnDestroy execute before ngOnInit was completelly executed

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
ngOnDestroy() {
   if (!!object) { // check if the object is not null with the double bang (!!)
     object.stop(); // if it is truthy, then go ahead and call the stop method.
   }
}
```

Comment: I already tryed that solution, but "object" is alway undefined.